# Adding a Newline Character at the End of a Line in a Column

Tags: python, file-io

The file my function reads is of the format:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Value2  Value1  Value4  Value3
Value7  Value6  Value5  Value8
Value9  Value10 Value11 Value12
```

I read the file, filter and sort it and am left with a list of lists of the format:

`lines = [[Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4], [Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4], [Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8]]`

Now when I try to write to a file (in the same format as my original file), I am not able to properly format my output. This is my code:

```
for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line[0].strip()+'\t')
        outfile.write(line[1].strip()+'\t')
        outfile.write(line[2].strip()+'\t')
        outfile.write(line[3].strip()+'\t')
```

If I change it to `outfile.write(line[0].strip()+'\t'+'\n')` or add `outfile.write('\n')`, my file is just one big column with all values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me, the problem I see is that you're not adding a newline after one row has been written.

```
>>> with open('fileName', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in lines:
            for elem in line:
                outFile.write(elem.strip()+'\t')
            outFile.write('\n')
```

This gave me an output like the following

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  
Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
```

for

```
>>> lines = [['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'], ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'], ['Value5', 'Value6', 'Value7', 'Value8']]
```

**EDIT** - To get the output you're looking for, use

```
>>> with open('fileName', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in lines:
                outFile.write("\t".join([elem.strip() for elem in line]))
            outFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hey I just have a small problem when I added this to my code. I get `[Value1\tValue2\tValue3\tValue4\t\n]` but I need `[Value1\tValue2\tValue3\tValue4\n]` without the last `\t` at the end of `Value4`. Any ideas how I could remove that extra tab?

Comment: @new_programmer : Hi! See the edit please, this should work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `string.join(list)` function, which concatenates the elements of `list`, separating them by `string`. So you'll want `"\t".join(x.strip() for x in line)`. But this alone doesn't give you the newlines at the end of each string. You could then add the newline afterwards as follows: `"\t".join(x.strip() for x in line) + "\n"`

And if you want to do all the lines together, you can make it `"\n".join('\t'.join(x.strip() for x in line) for line in lines)`

Also, if you use the `print >>outfile, string` syntax, you can get the newlines after each line automatically:

```
for line in lines:
    print >>outfile, '\t'.join(x.strip() for x in line)
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are good.
However I would recommend to use csv.reader and csv.writter